# How to display loading image or text while processing

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my project i am checking links whether its working or not ,when i click on create link button i want to display please wait for while but when and when if their some text in text box1if textbox1.text == null then it should not be display and when its not null then when i will click create button it should show please wait,my code is working but i want to check if their is some value in text box and user click the create button it should show please wait a while .if their no value in textbox1 then if user click on create button then please wait should not be displayed

here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">       

            function ShowProgressBar() {
                if (Textbox1.Text == " ") {
                    document.getElementById('dvProgressBar').style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('dvProgressBar').style.visibility = "visible";
                }
            }        
    </script>

      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Create link" OnClick="btn_createlink_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:ShowProgressBar()" />

    <br />
        <div ID="dvProgressBar" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <div id="content" style="text-align: left; " > 
         Please wait for while...
      </div>
      </div>

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="373px" 
        Width="410px" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you are only asking how to verify if the checkbox is empty, right? This should do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">       

function ShowProgressBar() {
    if (document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value == "") {
         document.getElementById('dvProgressBar').style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else {
         document.getElementById('dvProgressBar').style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}        
</script>
```

Comment: hey if want to add another textbox to check then? @nmat

Comment: @hitarth `if (document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value == "" && document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').value == "" )`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is probably to use `ajax`. Simply call a web service and use javascript to show a loading message/icon/whatever for the user. Try to use google for this, it's really straightforward.

It has to be asynchronous, or else it would block your UI and the `please wait` wouldn't show.

Comment: that only i am doing .i am calling javascript only

Comment: @hitarth, yep, except it has to be an asynchronous request, the reason is updated in the answer...